# How to programmatically expand a specific pannel in Ant design collapse

Tags: reactjs, antd

I want to expand a specific pannel of the Ant design collapse by clicking the next button it should expand the next panel. Here is the [codesandbox link](https://codesandbox.io/s/ghost-collapse-antd-4-23-4-forked-y1w7hh?file=/demo.js). Here is the screenshot of it as well.

[image: Screenshot]

Answer (score 0):

You just need to save the key in state of panel that you want to open it. You want to open the second panel when button in first panel is clicked. You save that Panel key is state and need to pass that active key to Collapse as a prop.

```
const App: React.FC = () => {
  const [activeKey, setActiveKey] = useState(1);

  function handleClick(key) {
    setActiveKey(key);
  }

  return (
    <Collapse defaultActiveKey={["1"]} activeKey={activeKey} ghost>
      <Panel header='This is panel header 1' key='1'>
        <p>{text}</p>
        <button onClick={() => handleClick("2")}>Next</button>
      </Panel>
      <Panel header='This is panel header 2' key='2'>
        <p>{text}</p>
        <button onClick={() => handleClick("3")}>Next</button>
      </Panel>
      <Panel header='This is panel header 3' key='3'>
        <p>{text}</p>
      </Panel>
    </Collapse>
  );
};

export default App;
```

Since you didn't provide specify whether it should close the existing panel or not. It does close the existing panel then above solution fines. But if you want to open multiple panels at a time then you need to change the code.

`<Collapse activeKey={activeKey}>`

You can activeKey as an array instead of string or number. In array you can pass any number of Panel keys like this: `['1', '2', ...]`.

Check the [Antd Collapse API](https://ant.design/components/collapse/#API)

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution finally

```
const App: React.FC = () => {
const [activeKey, setActiveKey] = useState(['1']);
  function handleClick(key) {
    console.log(key)
    setActiveKey(key);
  }

  return (
    <Collapse
      defaultActiveKey={["1"]}
      activeKey={activeKey}
      ghost
      onChange={handleClick}
    >
      <Panel header="This is panel header 1" key="1">
        <p>{text}</p>
        <button value='2' onClick={(e) => handleClick(e.target.value)}>Next</button>
      </Panel>
      <Panel header="This is panel header 2" key="2">
        <p>{text}</p>
        <button value='3' onClick={(e) => handleClick(e.target.value)}>Next</button>
      </Panel>
      <Panel header="This is panel header 3" key="3">
        <p>{text}</p>
      </Panel>
    </Collapse>
  );
};

export default App;
```

Here is the [codesandbox link](https://codesandbox.io/s/collapsible-antd-4-23-4-forked-s0q2uq?file=/demo.js:332-1112)